# Unable to run 2 nodemon inspect programs at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, nodemon

Background: running Ubuntu 19.10 on an Inspiron 560.

I have 2 different Discord bots that I need to run on the same computer (all my other throwaway machines have other uses currently and do not have the remaining power to run discord bots). I like using nodemon with inspect, as it helps catch a bunch of discord gateway errors, and I can auto restart after a crash. However, when running two bots with --inspect, nodemon kicks out the following error:

```
Starting inspector or 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
```

How can I run two `--inspect`s at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different addresses:

```
--inspect=127.0.0.1:9228
--inspect=127.0.0.1:9229
```

Comment: hello again! I tried and node spits back the following:
`node: bad option: --inspect=127.0.0.1:9228`
anything you can recommend to do?